# I need to select all classes and display them like currency Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to select all classes and display them like currency . Also it need to be displayed like a function . It need to update everytime I add some data . I tried a lot of stuff , nothing helped .

I now I need to make it with **each** . I got an error *toFixed is not a function*

```
$('.dashboard__currency').each(function(){
    return $(this).text().toFixed(2).replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$&,');
});
```

Is the any solutions ?

Comment: Also, provide array data or how will we work on it?

Comment: Strings don't have `toFixed` method. Convert the text to number before fixing it: `+($(this).text()). ...`.

Comment: What is `.dashboard__currency` here? div, textbox, textarea, span, etc?

Comment: @palaѕн .dashboard__currency is span that contains some number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two issues here. Firstly the error you get is because `text()` returns a string, yet `toFixed()` is a method of Number types. The second problem is that a `return` in an `each()` statement does not update the content of the element.

To fix this you can use `parseFloat()` to convert the string to a number, and you can also provide a function to `text()` which then returns the new value. This negates the need for the explicit `each()` call. Try this:

```js
$('.dashboard__currency').text((i, t) => parseFloat(t).toFixed(2).replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$&,'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="dashboard__currency">10205.99</span><br />
<span class="dashboard__currency">15232323.00</span><br />
<span class="dashboard__currency">193235</span>
```